# How to get message sender (author) of telegram channel using TLSharp

Tags: c#, api, telegram

I have a c# program that using `TLSharp` library to extract data from a Telegram channel. I want to get sender id of each post but I'm getting null when I try to retrieve `FromID` value of each `TLMessage` object. Here is my key part of code:

```
// Get Channel Messages
var history = await client.GetHistoryAsync(target, 0, -1, 100) as TLChannelMessages;

// Show Message Sender Id For Each Message
foreach (var message in history.Messages.OfType<TLMessage>())
{
    MessageBox.Show(message.FromId.Value.ToString());
}
```

Unfortunately `message.FromId` is `Null` in every foreach iteration.
I need this program so much please help me!

Comment: It's impossible since there have only first name.

Comment: What about getting message sender name? @Sean